# CSV first letter of line moved to end of field

Tags: csv, sed

I have a CSV file that I would like to move the first letter to the end of the first string and insert an underscore in front of the last two characters. I can't find anything on how to move a letter over with sed. Here is my example CSV:

```
name,number,number1,status,mode 
B9AT0582B41,430,30,0,Loop
B8AU0302D11,448,0,0,Loop
B8AU0302D21,448,0,0,Loop
B8AU0302D31,448,0,0,Loop
B8AU0302D41,448,0,0,Loop
```

For example, the `B9AT0582B41`, I want it to be `9AT0582B_41B`.

It needs to do this for each line and not change the state of the other CSV values.

I am open to forms other than sed.

Comment: Is the underscore in `_41B` a typo?

Comment: No i need the underscore also

Comment: Where does it go? The question doesn't mention it anywhere.

Comment: 9AT0582B_41B, needs to be between the character and last two digits (with the trailing B that has already been moved to the end of the string)...it should be the 9th column in each line without it overwriting the 9th column.

Comment: @Hunter - if it's part of the solution you're looking for, describe it [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47598929/edit), not in a comment..  Given that your question mentions `sed`, I'd also expect your question to include the `sed` code you already wrote while trying to solve this yourself, along with an example of the output (or error) that your code generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on this.

```
$ sed -E 's/(.)(.{8})([^,]*)(.*)/\2_\3\1\4/' <<<"B9AT0582B41,430,30,0,Loop"
9AT0582B_41B,430,30,0,Loop
```

This uses an extended regular expression to make things easier to read. Sed's `-E` option causes the RE to be interpreted in extended notation. If your version of sed doesn't support this, check your man page to see if there's another option that does the same thing, or you can try to use BRE notation:

```
$ sed 's/\(.\)\(.\{8\}\)\([^,]*\)\(.*\)/\2_\3\1\4/' <<<"B9AT0582B41,430,30,0,Loop"
9AT0582B_41B,430,30,0,Loop
```

Answer (score 3):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, \
    'NR > 1 { $1 = substr($1, 2, 8) "_" substr($1, 10) substr($1, 1, 1) } 1' infile
name,number,number1,status,mode
9AT0582B_41B,430,30,0,Loop
8AU0302D_11B,448,0,0,Loop
8AU0302D_21B,448,0,0,Loop
8AU0302D_31B,448,0,0,Loop
8AU0302D_41B,448,0,0,Loop
```

This sets input and output field separator to `,`; then, for each line (except the first one) rearranges the first field (three calls to `substr`), then prints the line (the `1` at the end).

Or sed, a bit shorter:

```
sed -E '2,$s/^(.)([^,]*)([^,]{2})/\2_\3\1/' infile
```

This captures the first letter of each line (for lines 2 and up) in capture group 1, then everything up to two characters before the first comma in capture group 2 and the last two characters before the comma in capture group 3. The substitution then swaps and adds the underscore.

Comment: @Hunter, you have an example of how to use the `substr()` function. Can you answer your own question? Here is a reference to other awk built-in string functions: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html

Comment: @hunter I've edited your question to mention the underscore, and updated the answer.